# building an insert statement with many values of different datatypes

Tags: php, mysql

I am borrowing this code that was entering strings (user, message) into shoutbox table as strings in the database

```
function insertMessage($user, $message){
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO shoutbox(user, message) VALUES('%s', '%s');",
        mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($user)),
        mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($message))
    );
```

However, I am changing the data and actually inserting several different datatypes, (i.e. in the database they will be "strings" and "tinyint").  Function insertMessage is now going to be called with these many different _POST values

```
   echo insertMessage(
       $_POST['drafting'], 
       $_POST['advocacy'], 
       $_POST['interview'],
       $_POST['letter'],
       $_POST['solicitor'],
       $_POST['barrister'],
       $_POST['instructor'],
       $_POST['secret']
   );
```

--drafting, advocacy, interview, letter, solicitor, barrister are going into the database as  "tinyint" and need intval called on them to make them integers

--instructor and secret are both going into the database as "strings"

My questions are

a) how to mix the tinyint data (and call intval on it) with the strings while escaping the strings

b) is there a way to do this without building a mega long insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `intval()` on the values, `mysql_real_escape_string()` will work on numbers too (make sure you continue to quote them).

Comment: but does mysql_real_escape convert the string to an integer?  Is there a way to write the long insert statement in a compact way?

Comment: MySQL will coerce whatever you give it to the proper datatype for the column (so you can give a TINYINT column a `'1'`), and the `mysql` driver will return everything *from* the database as a string. PHP programmers get astonishingly lazy about datatypes with MySQL.

Comment: @alex sorry about that...in the form, the values for "drafting, advocacy, interview, letter, solicitor, barrister" will all be 0 or 1 but they are technically "string"s, and I'm putting them into the database as type tinyint, so I was going to convert the strings 1 and 0 from the form to actual integers. make sense?

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.2.0+ has a configurable [filter extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) that can help.

```
<?php

$sql_int = array(
  'filter'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
);

$sql_string = array(
  'filter'     => FILTER_CALLBACK,
  'options'    => 'mysql_real_escape_string'
);

echo inputMessage(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
 'drafting'   => $sql_int,
 'advocacy'   => $sql_int,
 'interview'  => $sql_int,
 'letter'     => $sql_int,
 'solicitor'  => $sql_int,
 'barrister'  => $sql_int,
 'instructor' => $sql_string,
 'secret'     => $sql_string
)));

function inputMessage(array $input) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function accepts 2 parameters and you're feeding it 8? That's not going to work.

Comment: The function will *accept* an arbitrarily list of arguments, even if only two are named. See `func_get_args()`.

Comment: @alex: certainly, although not with his particular implementation.

Comment: sorry, the code in the first part is the code I borrowed, I haven't changed the number of parameters yet, but that's part of the point, I'm going to be putting 8 into the database, so I want to make it more compact. With only 2 paramaters currently, the function is kind of messy looking...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple function (or method) like this which will work for simple inserts. It will escape values and handle nulls. It can't handle functions though (like sha1( value ) for example )

```
<?php
function insertArray( $table, $data, $dbConn ) {
    $keys = array_keys( $data );

    foreach( $data as &$val ) {
        if( is_null( $val ) ) {
             $val = 'NULL';
        } else {
             $val = "'".mysql_real_escape_string( $val )."'";
        }
    }
    unset( $val );

    $sql = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO `%s` (`%s`) VALUES (%s)',
        $table,
        implode( '`, `', $keys ),
        implode( ', ', $data )
    );

    //you probably want to handle errors here
    mysql_query( $sql, $dbConn );
    return mysql_insert_id( $dbConn );
}

//Example

$newId = insertArray(
    'my_table',
    array(
        'drafting'   => $_POST['drafting'], 
        'advocacy'   => $_POST['advocacy'], 
        'interview'  => $_POST['interview'],
        'letter'     => $_POST['letter'],
        'solicitor'  => $_POST['solicitor'],
        'barrister'  => $_POST['barrister'],
        'instructor' => $_POST['instructor'],
        'secret'     => $_POST['secret']
    ),
    $dbConnection
);
```